# Maclaurin expansion of $f(x)=e^{ax^{1/2}}$ with undefined derivative at $0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I am asked to find the Maclaurin expansion of the following function:

\begin{equation} 
 f(x)=e^{ax^{1/2}}
\end{equation}

I have trouble understanding how to do that given that the first derivative of the function (for example) is undefined at $0$.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For starters you can also try $\tan x$ which has undefined derivatives at $\pi/2$!

Comment: A Maclaurin expansion exists only when the function is infinitely differentiable at $0$.  This one is not.

Comment: This function doesn't have a Maclaurin series at $0$. As @GEdgar pointed out, $f$ needs to be infinitely differentiable at $0$ for this to be the case, and you observed that it doesn't even have a first-order derivative at $0$.

Comment: So the error is from the person who asked you to find this.  Maybe he said something else?  A Laurent series?  A Taylor series?

Answer (score 0):

The function doesn't have a Maclaurin series for the reason that you have said (the first derivative is undefined at $0$), but we still know that for any $x$ we have
$$e^x=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^r}{r!}$$
Hence,
$$f(x)=e^{ax^{1/2}}=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a\sqrt x)^r}{r!}$$
I hope that is somewhat helpful.

Comment: Maclaurin/Taylor series results in non negative integral powers of $x$. Here people like $x^{0.5},x^{1.5}$ etc. are present so why do you think that it is still Maclaurin?

Comment: @Koro I definitely din't think that it's a Maclaurin series, I was just providing *a* series expansion that may be useful to the OP.

Comment: I saw this question yesterday and I was posting exactly what you have posted but then it occured to me that it's not Maclaurin. I think the answer to OPs question is Maclaurin doesn't exist for this function. Right?

Comment: @Koro right :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since
$e^x
=\cosh(x)+\sinh(x)
$,

$e^{ax^{1/2}}
=\cosh(a\sqrt{x})+\sinh(a\sqrt{x})
$.

As $x \to 0$,
$\cosh(a\sqrt{x})$
behaves nicely
but
$\sinh(a\sqrt{x})
\approx a\sqrt{x}
$
which does not have a derivative
at $x = 0$.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers